# How can I solve an infinity error using try-catch blocks?

Tags: java, math, try-catch

I am trying to debug my program where it can catch all errors outside of integer value and report using try-catch.  When I enter a string I get infinite loopback and can't figure out how to stop it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.ArithmeticException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Divide {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        double ratio;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1; // using variable for do-while loop

        do { // re-runs code if input error
            try {
                System.out.println("Let's divide some numbers!");
                System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
                num1 = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
                num2 = scan.nextInt();
                ratio = ((double) num1 / num2);
                System.out.println("Eureka!  the answer is " + ratio);
                x = 2;
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println("No division by zero!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("This won't work. Try again.");
            }

        } while (x == 1);
    }
}
```

Output:
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first whole number: Y
Wrong input: nullLet's divide some numbers!
Enter your first whole number: Wrong input: nullLet's divide some numbers!
Enter your first whole number: Wrong input: nullLet's divide some numbers!

Comment: By adding a `break;` or updating `x`.

Comment: this works, but I have to continue to call for input until I get proper input.  If I put in a string, the program just runs and i have to force stop.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thank you for revising.  this helps a lot although I' getting a compiling error when inputting text into int variable.  I will work on this some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Divide {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        double ratio;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1; // using variable for do-while loop

        do { // re-runs code if input error
            try {
                System.out.println("Let's divide some numbers!");
                System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
                num1 = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
                num2 = scan.nextInt();
                if (num2 != 0) {
                    ratio = ((double) num1 / num2);
                    System.out.println("Eureka!  the answer is " + ratio);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The second number should not be 0");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("This won't work. Try again.");
                x = 2;
            }
        } while (x == 1);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first number: 10
Enter your second number: 5
Eureka!  the answer is 2.0
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first number: 12
Enter your second number: 0
The second number should not be 0
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first number: 23
Enter your second number: 5
Eureka!  the answer is 4.6
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first number: 50
Enter your second number: abc
This won't work. Try again.
```

Program will stop execution at this point.

**Update:** I just saw your comment that you don't want your program to stop even with illegal input (e.g. abc). For this, all you need to do is to instantiate the `Scanner` object again. Given below is the complete program with sample run:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Divide {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        double ratio;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1; // using variable for do-while loop

        do { // re-runs code if input error
            try {
                System.out.println("Let's divide some numbers!");
                System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
                num1 = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
                num2 = scan.nextInt();
                if (num2 != 0) {
                    ratio = ((double) num1 / num2);
                    System.out.println("Eureka!  the answer is " + ratio);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The second number should not be 0");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("This won't work. Try again.");
                scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            }
        } while (x == 1);
    }
}
```

**Sample run:**

```
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first number: 10
Enter your second number: 5
Eureka!  the answer is 2.0
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first number: 10
Enter your second number: 0
The second number should not be 0
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first number: 10
Enter your second number: abc
This won't work. Try again.
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first number: 10
Enter your second number: 5
Eureka!  the answer is 2.0
Let's divide some numbers!
Enter your first number:
```

I hope, this fulfils your requirement. Feel free to let me know if you needed something else.

Now, you can even remove the redundant variable, `x` as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Divide {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        double ratio;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) { 
            try {
                System.out.println("Let's divide some numbers!");
                System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
                num1 = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
                num2 = scan.nextInt();
                if (num2 != 0) {
                    ratio = ((double) num1 / num2);
                    System.out.println("Eureka!  the answer is " + ratio);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The second number should not be 0");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("This won't work. Try again.");
                // re-runs code if input error
                scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            }
        }
    }
}
```